# ExpressJS GET and POST on same route

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express

Basically I am trying to put together a questionnaire in Express JS with EJS as the renderer.  I have the pages populated, one for each question.  The pages can be accessed with static links using the app.get('/question/:number?', routes.questions); function.  The part I am confused on is how can I also perform a POST using the same routes.  When they complete question 1, I want to post the answer in a temporary location (variable), and also load the next question.  There are 4 questions in total.  When they complete the 4th question, a different submit button is on the html page...this button should take all 4 answers and save it in a json file locally on the filesystem.

I am hoping someone could put together a quick example of this using generic code to give me a hint on how to complete these.  Once I get one working, I think the overall functionality should be much clearer to me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is add something like this:

```
app.post('/question/:number', function(req, res) {
    var qid = Number(req.params.number);
    var answer = req.body.answer; // <input name="answer" .../>
    // store answer
    answers[qid] = answer;
    // load next question
    if (qid < 4) res.redirect('/question/' + (qid + 1));
    else res.redirect('/results');
});
```

Comment: Everything works fine except for one strange hiccup.  The 'qid + 1' is actually returning 11 instead of 2, when I am on question 1.  I am trying to figure out why it would do that since the syntax seems logical.

Comment: Right; params are all strings. Try `var qid = Number(req.params.number);`